# Short story: alien disguised as human, can't fool job recruiter

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The synopsis I remember is: there is a job recruiter (I believe) that is able to identify an alien that looks like a human and after talking with the alien for a bit the alien heads out to perfect his mannerisms and such and comes back a while later (a few months?) and is recognized again

Comment: "What Have I Done?" by Mark Clifton. See this old answer for more information: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92922/employment-office-encounters-an-alien-masquerading-as-a-human/92923#92923

Comment: this is exactly it! Thank you so much. I'm not sure how to close the question though